# Will this div be stretched so that the button will not overlap?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way I can change the css of the wordpress plug in so it will fit in the theme? It does show perfectly on mobile view though, but desktop view overlaps.

The add to cart button overlaps to the menu item: https://rjbenspizzabuhangin.com/order/

I tried to change the position: relative to other possible style but none works!

Answer (score 0):

Change it

```
.rp-col-md-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
```

to this

```
.rp-col-md-9 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

at resolution @media (min-width: 992px)

Comment: Still did not work. I tried adding !important and doesnt work